# dotnetZip How to write to specific folder with memoryStream

Tags: .net, zip, dotnetzip

I need to create a zip file containing a folder structure and be able to add files from a memory stream to specific folders.

I am trying to achieve this with [dotnetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) but they seem to have dropped support for adding a file by stream to a specific folder.

All examples I can find use the following:

> zip.AddEntry("test.txt", "folder", memoryStream);

But this method no longer allows you to add a folder name into which to add the file.

> zip.AddEntry("test.txt", memoryStream);

How can I use dotnetZip to create a child folder in a zip file and add a memoryStream file to that folder without having to save to disk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entry path can include directories inside of archive, so you should first

> .AddEntry("folderName/")

, next -

> .AddEntry("folderName/filename.txt", memoryStream);

Comment: Thank, Found out you only need .AddEntry("folder/file", stream); I had the slash the wrong way round

Comment: also AddEntry("foldername/") won't work as the method doesn't have an overload for only one parameter

Comment: Probably, it should be spelled as AddEntry("foldername/", null), cannot try the code right now.

Comment: Nickolay Olshevsky,  for empty folders    .AddEntry("foldername/", new byte[] { });